# Gnome Locale settings don't seem to work in 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: gnome, locale

I set the Formats to UK in Settings>Region&Language.Formats. On the preview it shows the date as 12 Dec but as you can see on the attached, at the top of the desktop the date is shown as Dec 12.

Also, Thunderbird uses US formats.

And the locale dump at the terminal output shows everything as "en_US" as below.

```
~/Desktop$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8 
LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

Also, I found this which matches my GNOME settings:

```
$ more /etc/default/locale
"#"  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_GB:en"
```

I maybe can half understand the Thunderbird picking up some erroneous parameter but can't get my head round the gnome desktop itself getting it wrong!

The GUI settings haven't changed since I upgraded to 22.4 when it first came out, so many restarts in-between.

What am I doing wrong?
[image: Region and Language]
[image: Region format settings and the desktop]

Answer (score 0):

The order of the components in the date string in the top bar is determined by the current language, not the format. If you change also the language to en_GB (and relogin) you should notice a difference.

Comment: That was also long set to UK. I have added a second picture with the Region&Language view.

Comment: @Levo48: Hmm.. Then can you please edit your question again and show the complete output of the `locale` terminal command.

Comment: It is already in the question, all the locale outputs are en_US. My immediate problem is not with the locale command and where its settings are stored in the system, it is with gnome. One would expect that as a minimum there should be consistency within an application and the GNOME settings should at least apply to the GNOME desktop itself. As per the figures, I have set the region etc using the GNOME GUI and expect the GNOME to use these. Am I wrong? Having misleading settings is worse than not having them.

Comment: @Levo48: Note that I asked for the **complete** output.

Comment: Thanks for being patient Gunnar. locale output added as requested. Had to make it a bullet list as the editor makes everything flat text and I couldn't figure out another way.

Comment: @Levo48: Somewhere you have explicitly set the `LC_ALL` variable to "en_US.UTF-8", which overrides most other locale related variables and most likely explains the behavior. `LC_ALL` should *never* be set persistently on a desktop. I can't tell in which file you set it, but you may want to look at the `/etc/environment` file.

Comment: Thanks Gunnar. Although i dabbed in Unix/Linux in the past my main background is Windows. So when I moved to Ubuntu, it was based on the premise that it can easily replace Windows. Although every now and then I am forced to go to the terminal, I pretty much try to avoid it. So based on that, I don't think and/or remember I changed any environment variables other that through GUI and the environment file you mention has only some folder paths, i.e. usr/local:usr/bin:.... If anything I would always try to set these to UK where I can.

Comment: Also, if the LC_ALL is the mother of all, why would GNOME GUI not set it? As I said, I for one and other people like me coming from Windows would expect that once the GUI is set, it should find any and all locale related parameters and set them so the system  works as expected. Otherwise what's the point of having a GUI.  On the other hand the experts who want to override these parameters should either leave the GNOME to us novices or GNOME should have an "I_am_an_expert" toggle that blanks out these settings. This may need to be raised as a request or something.

Comment: @Levo48: AFAIK there is no GUI to set `LC_ALL`, and normally it should be unset. I suspect that you at some point followed some bad advice. Some other files you want to check out: `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile`, and the files in the `/etc/profile.d` directory.